# INVALID_ID_FIELD, SaveAsActivity is not allowed with whatId that is not supported as a task whatId

Tags: apex, visualforce, email-template, leads, activities

I have an `email template` which is configured like this:

```
recipientType="Contact" relatedToType="Lead"
```

The email is sent using this:

```
mail.setWhatId(leadId);
mail.setTargetObjectId(contactId);
mail.setSaveAsActivity(true);
```

But I am getting this error:

> INVALID_ID_FIELD, SaveAsActivity is not allowed with whatId that is not supported as a task whatId

Which seems to relate to the fact that `Lead` does not have `Track Activities` enabled.

**Questions**

1. How can I enable `Track Activities` on `Lead`?
2. How can I send an email to the `Contact` about the `Lead` which is tracked in the activity timeline for both objects?

Comment: I read Robs as asking whether there exists a solution to that problem, which they already know about. The linked question doesn't propose any solutions.